# Autonomy developer info sources

Tags: autonomy, interwoven, hp-haven, hp-idol-ondemand

Does anyone know some site where I can find information about autonomy??
I'm looking after code samples, architecture posts, and things like that, both about

- autonomy IDOL search engine
- autonomy interwoven content management server

side note:

> I cannot understand why there're so many barriers to access theese product's developer resources. I thought that HP would change autonomy's policy about this but It stills the same: there's absolutely NO access to libraries, code samples, etc... you're forced to have a partner account...
>   If I could I'd move to opener alternatives... but it's not completly in my hand ;-(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is little public information available about Autonomy's products. 
The best way forward is to build your own network of people who know the product and have had experience with implementations.

The information that is shipped with the product can also help. Specifically regarding the Autonomy IDOL server and the calls you can make - some resources

- **The IDOL Administrator manual**: Probably the most complete document available. It will help you understand the components which make up an IDOL architecture. However, it will not go into too much detail on complex architectures.
- **The Online Help**: (http://:/a=help) Most components have an online help which documents all the calls and parameters.
- **The GRL**: (http://:/a=grl) Gives you the most recent commands sent to a component. The best way to 'reverse engineer' how to components are interacting with each other.

I found that most active discussions regarding Autonomy's product suite can be found [here](http://knowledgemanagement.ittoolbox.com/groups/technical-functional/autonomy-l/).